Word for items in a schedule
What would be the right word to use for individual items in a schedule or timetable?
Imagine a schedule with the following entries

Do A every day at 5:32 pm
Do B on August 7th, 2026 at 5:42 pm
Do C every 38 minutes
Do D every last Wednesday of every month

What would you call each of those lines?

Any reason for not using "entries" or "schedule entries" as given in the question?

@KillingTime The fact that there are many different entries for many different tables. Using “entry” would require specifying to what table the entry belongs. Think “distance” vs “distances entry”.

"planned tasks" ?

@Graffito Yes, in Computer Science you normally talk about “scheduled tasks”. Just wanted to know if there's a specific word for them.

What kind of schedule or timetable? Is this things a computer does automatically like unix cron, which calls them jobs or scheduled commands, or in a calendar app for humans, which my phone calls events?

I find that telling myself I have an appointment to visit a friend in hospital means I'll do it. Rather than just scheduled to do it.

Is there any real reason why you need an abstract term that will suit every possible schedule? The best real-life solution would seem to be to use a specific term for whatever the schedule is about (such as meeting, lecture, delivery, departure).

For that particular list: to-do for singular. For plural...

That’s not a schedule. That’s a list of events, some periodic or repeating, to be placed on a schedule.

You need a slightly longer string:

List item

The individual elements that make up the list are called list items. [Webflow University]


Though the article refers to lists/items in a particular presentation, the term works for all lists.

This assumes that everyone will think of 'Do B on August 7th, 2026 at 5:42 pm' as one item, rather than, say, three (action, date, time). This is reasonable, but not guaranteed. Thinking of a schedule as something like a spreadsheet, the OP is looking for a word that treats each row as one item, but in another possible way of counting items, there may be several items in a row. The word entry is ambiguous in the same way.

Once we get away from general lists to say ordered triples, we are off-topic wrt ELU/standard everyday English, and into subject-specific areas.

The CMSD (Core Manufacturing Simulation Data) "standard" uses
Schedule consists of "schedule items" ...
Depending on context, in manufacturing, we may use "jobs" or "tasks" to describe items on a schedule, but thats context dependent of course.
Disclaimer: This is an answer to your question not for your unrelated example sentences.
